# Java SQLite3 Connection Failing

Tags: java, database, sqlite, connect

I am having some trouble connecting my java script to my SQLite3 database.

I have my directory holding my script as followed

```
C:/PROG/JavaPROG/programs/java_database
```

Inside this directory I have 3 files

```
Query.java, Query.class and the database query.db
```

My java code looks as followed

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Query3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Connection conn = null;

        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:/PROG/JavaPROG/programs/java_database/query.db");
            System.out.println("Connection Success");
        } catch(Exception log) {
            System.out.println("Connection Failed: " + log);
        }

    }

}
```

my classpath does contain

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin
```

and inside that bin directory is the sqlite jdbc driver

```
sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar
```

I can connect my script to PostgreSQL database but I can't see why it isn't connecting to the SQLite3, I am getting the following error message

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC
```

have I done something wrong?

Comment: "I am having some trouble connecting my java script". This is what you said. Where is the javascript? Btw, did you try google. Most people reading this question are going to give you the answer from there. Nobody remembers stuff like this. As a developer, knowing how to find answers on Google goes a long way in maintaining a good work life balance.

Comment: the javascript? you lost me there bot?

Comment: Oh I see, I meant a script written in java not actual JavaScript. I have googled it although everything keeps saying that the sqlite jdbc driver is missing but I'm sure it's in my classpath so I'm just seeing if anyone knows of anything else while I continue googling

Comment: also I see a lot of stuff I find in google answers the issue for people working in Netbeans, Eclipse etc but I am coding from the command line so I didn't find them very helpful

Comment: hey bot I found the answer and posted it bellow, you were pretty close

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found the answer to fix this.

compile the script as normal

```
javac Query.java
```

Then specify the driver when executing

```
java -classpath ".;sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar" Query
```

And it will run fine

Comment: I have already covered that in my answer. Your answer does not add anything new that I have not already covered. I guess you missed the last line from my answer? Btw, it is impossible that your javac command works without the classpath option but the java command requires the classpath option. Can you explain how you are able to compile without giving the classpath?

Comment: The javac command compiles the program perfectly, as I said in my question the jdbc driver is already in the path. It was ignoring the driver when I ran the script using the Java command so I needed to include the driver when running the program as well, your answer was not wrong but it added an unnecessary javac -cp step and was not 100% clear. Thank you for your help though because it helped me look at other options

Comment: The jdbc driver is not in your path. The folder where the jdbc driver is present is in your path. This should not work since jar files are not looked for in the path while using javac. If java requires the classpath, javac should require it too.

Comment: If that's true then I have no idea but it always has been compiling fine it just never ran

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly provide the `sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar` file in your classpath while compiling and running your classes using the `-cp` option. The java and javac commands will only look for .class files in the classpath and not jars.

Try this :

`javac -cp <path_to_jar/sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar>;. <your_class_name>.java`

And if you have more than one thirdparty library, you can use a wildcard :

`javac -cp <path_to_jar/*>;. <your_class_name>.java`

Note that `;` is the separator used in Windows. If you are on unix based systems, you need to use `:` instead of `;`. Java maybe platform independant but the java and javac commands are not.

Also note that the `.` tells the java and javac commands to look in the current directory for classes. Don't forget to provide the classpath to the jars when running your program using the `java` command.

Comment: whaaat that's hectic, like javac Query.java -cp sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar?

Comment: @Trent See my edit. Let me know if you need more inputs. If not, don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: I'm afraid it didn't work but I really appreciate your help, I'm going to keep googling :'{

Comment: @Trent Not sure why it didn't work. Are you still getting exactly the same error or a new error this time? There is no other reason why you should get the error posted in your question other than not putting the jars in the classpath.

Comment: the same error, I even put the sqlite driver in the same directory as the main class

Comment: It would be interesting to know what the issue was if you have already tried my suggestions. Do let me know..